# Collectionview inside tableview causing issue with 2 columns

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, autosize

I have vertical collection-view inside tableview cell. collection view contain feature of load more too. for self sizing of collection view, i make tableview cell automaticDimension.
Also i have give height constant to collection-view. first time its loaded correctly but once i go to last cell and its load-more after reloading it create lot of space after collection view. can any one let me know what i am doing wrong here. or is there any other way around to make collection-view inside tableview self sizing so it increase tableview cell height too

**

- TableviewCell Class

**

```swift
justForYouCollectionView.dataSource = self
justForYouCollectionView.delegate = self
justForYouCollectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
self.collectionHeight.constant = self.justForYouCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
justForYouCollectionView.reloadData()

override func systemLayoutSizeFitting(_ targetSize: CGSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority horizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority, verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority) -> CGSize {
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
    let contentSize = self.justForYouCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize
    return CGSize(width: contentSize.width, height: contentSize.height + 20)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == self.justForYouArray.count - 1 && self.isLoadMore {
        updateNextSet()
    }
}
```

**

- CollectionViewCell Class

**

```swift
override func preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
    let autoLayoutAttributes = super.preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(layoutAttributes)
    
    // Specify you want _full width_
    let targetSize = CGSize(width: layoutAttributes.frame.width, height: 0)
    
    // Calculate the size (height) using Auto Layout
    let autoLayoutSize = contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(targetSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority.required, verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority.defaultLow)
    let autoLayoutFrame = CGRect(origin: autoLayoutAttributes.frame.origin, size: autoLayoutSize)
    
    // Assign the new size to the layout attributes
    autoLayoutAttributes.frame = autoLayoutFrame
    return autoLayoutAttributes
}
```

extra space can be seen in image

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have worked on that earlier all I did is, set tableview height constraint set in storyboard and drop its outlet in viewController then after populate data get array count and divide by 2 and after dividing I multiply it by CollectionViewCell height and set that height to the UITableView height constraint like this.

```
let count = (array.count / 2) * cellHeight
tableviewHeightConstraint.constant = CGFloat(count)
```

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
let a = (yourArray.count /2 ) * heightCell
tblViewHeightConstraint.constant = CGFloat(a)
```